# Are the meanings of conditions and combination the same?

Tags: pratityasamutpada

Anything which is a result of combination can be called conditional.

But is the opposite also true ?

That is anything which is conditional must be a result of combination.

For example - If there is a feeling then there must be a craving. This is a condition with no combination. However if you look closely feeling alone can not result in craving unless you are aware of the path leading to fulfilment of the feeling again. Therefore feeling with path awareness leads to cravings. Cravings result from combination of feelings and path awareness.

Another example would be - If the weather is cloudy , it will rain. Cloud itself can not bring rain unless it reaches a specific density. Therefore cloud and density of cloud are a must for a rain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For feeling & craving to occur in combination, there must also be the condition of ignorance. For example, when craving seeks fulfillment of a feeling, it is ignorance conditioning the craving. Or when feeling conditions craving, there must be ignorance acting with that feeling. For example, SN 22.81 says:

> To an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person, touched by that which is
> felt born of contact with ignorance, craving arises. That fabrication
> is born of that. And that fabrication is inconstant, fabricated,
> dependently co-arisen. That craving... That feeling... That contact...
> That ignorance is inconstant, fabricated, dependently co-arisen.